# Remove [...] from RSS feed Wordpress widget?

Tags: wordpress, rss, widget

I would like to remove the '[...]' from the RSS feed widget in my Wordpress site and replace it with '...'.

I have tried adding the following to functions:

```
function replace_ellipsis($text) {

$return = str_replace('[...]', '...', $text);
 return $return;
}
add_filter('get_the_excerpt', 'replace_ellipsis');
```

However, this does not affect the widget.

Any help?

Answer (score 1):

This is defined in v3.4.2 in `wp-includes/default-widgets.php`, lines 848 - 862. The only function that can be hooked into that I can see is `esc_html`, so here's what I use:

```
add_filter('esc_html', 'transform_ellipsis');
function transform_ellipsis($s_html) {
    return str_replace(' [&hellip;]', '&hellip;', $s_html);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It says here: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_excerpt_rss that it hooks to  'the_excerpt_rss', so perhaps this will work:

```
function new_excerpt_more( $excerpt ) {
    return str_replace( '[...]', '...', $excerpt );
}
add_filter( 'the_excerpt_rss', 'new_excerpt_more' );
```

if that doesn't work, see this page for more ways: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_excerpt#Remove_.5B....5D_string_using_Filters

Comment: The `the_excerpt_rss` filter can't change the `[...]`.